# Finding unique products (never seen before by a user) in a datastore sorted by a dynamically changing value (i.e. product rating)

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

been trying to solve this problem for a week and couldn't come up with any solutions in all my research so I thought I'd ask you all.

I have a "Product" table and a "productSent" table, here's a quick scheme to help explain:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty();
  rating = ndb.IntegerProperty

class productSent(ndb.Model): <--- the key name here is md5(Product Key+UUID)
  pId = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Product)
  uuId = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=userData)
  action = ndb.StringProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

My goal is to show users the highest rated product that they've never seen before--fast. So to keep track of the products users have seen, I use the productSent table. I created this table instead of using Cursors because every time the rating order changes, there's a possibility that the cursor skips the new higher ranking product. An example: assume the user has seen products 1-24 in the db. Next, 5 users liked product #25, making it the #10 product in the database--I'm worried that the product will never be shown again to the user (and possibly mess things up on a higher scale).

The problem with the way I'm doing it right now is that, once the user has blown past the first 1,000 products, it really starts slowing down the query performance. Because I'm literally pulling 1,000+ results, checking if they've been sent by querying against the productSent table (doing a keyName lookup to speed things up) and going through the loop until 15 new ones have been detected.

One solution I thought of was to add a repeated property (listProperty) to the Product table of all the users who have seen a product. Or if I don't want to have inequality filters I could put a repeated property of all the users who haven't seen a product. That way when I query I can dynamically take those out. But I'm afraid of what happens when I have 1,000+ users:

a) I'll go through the roof on the limit of repeated properties in one entity. 
b) The index size will increase size costs

Has anyone dealt with this problem before (I'm sure someone has!) Any tips on the best way to structure it?

**update**
Okay, so had another idea. In order to minimize the changes that take place when a rating (number of likes) changes, I could have a secondary column that only has 3 possible values: positive, neutral, negative. And sort by that? Ofcourse for items that have a rating of 0 and get a 'like' (making them a positive) would still have a chance of being out of order or skipped by the cursor--but it'd be less likely. What do y'all think?

Comment: I would consider dropping this feature for good. Keeping track in the server about the items seen by each user means having an entry per user and product, and in the end it's a waste of space and cycles. Either keep track of the items in the browser via LocalStorage, or better yet, just use a different link style for a:visited.

Comment: Thanks for the response @NachoColoma! Unfortunately the feature is a key part of our value proposition (it's a mobile app). That said--it doesn't need to be implemented perfectly. For example, if the user doesn't see an item because it gets catapulted above where their cursor currently is, it's not too big a deal because there's 20k+ products for the user to go through. So in a sense, it doesn't need to be precise!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the inverse, `productNotSent` would work well here.  Every time you add a new product, you would add a new `productNotSent` entity for each user.  When the user wants to see the highest rated product they have not seen, you will only have to query over the `productNotSent` entities that match that user.  If you put the `rating` directly on the `productNotSent` you could speed the query up even more, since you will only have to query against one Model.

Another idea would be to limit the number of `productNotSent` entities per user.  So each user only has ~100 of these entities at a time.  This would mean your query would be constant for each user, regardless of the number of products or users you have.  The creation of new `productNotSent` entities would become more complex, though.  You'd have to have a cron job or something that "tops up" a user's collection of `productNotSent` entities when they use some up.  You also may want to double-check that products rated higher than those already within the user's set of `productNotSent` entities get pushed in there.  These are a little more difficult and well require some design trade-offs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. I'm wondering though... is using the productNotSent approach only delaying the inevitable problems? As you mentioned topping the list up would be intensive. For example, when topping up, I'll re-sort the list of available products by rating and then go from top to bottom (comparing it against the productSent table) until I get lets say 100 more unseen products. Seems like the processing has to happen anyways and this method just delays it a bit. Is this correct?

Comment: also at @matt, wondering what you think about using cursors but running something in the backend to update the cursors **only of active users** if ratings change materially--is that even possible? lol :)

Comment: No, I don't think this is delaying the inevitable problems. In the case where you have 100 perfectly-rated `procuctNotSent` entities, you will never need to top it up b/c you will never find products rated higher than them.  Running the top-up task on a backend for only the users/entities that have changed makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your expected volumes and exact issues (only did a quick perusal of your question), but you may consider using Json TextProperty storage as part of your plan. Create dictionaries/lists and store them in records by json.dump()ing them to a TextProperty. When the client calls, simply send the TextProperties to the client, and figure everything out on the client side once you JSON.parse() them. We have done some very large array/object processing in JS this way, and it is very fast (particularly indexed arrays). When the user clicks on something, send a transaction back to update their record. Set up some pull or push queue processes to handle your overall product listing updates, major customer rec updates, etc.

One downside is higher bandwidth going out of you app, but I think this cost will be minimal given potential processing savings on GAE. If you structure this right, you may be able to use get_by_id() to replace all or most of your planned indices and queries. We have found json.loads() and json.dumps() to be very fast inside the app, but we only use simple dictionary/list structures.This approach will be, though, a big, *big* quantum measure lower than your planned use of queries. The other potential issue is that very large objects may run into soft memory limits. Be sure that your Json objects are fairly simple+lightweight to avoid this (e.g. do no include product description, sub-objects, etc. in the Json item, just the basics such as product number). HTH, -stevep

Comment: Thanks @stevep. Will definitely keep this in mind. Any tips on resolving the issue with not being able to use cursors when sorting a table by a dynamic property? Since the order changes cursors aren't reliable.

Comment: You would be working with all the table elements in your object. To operate on the object you would json.loads() it in GAE Python, do your sorts/updates, then json.dumps() it to you TextProperty for client delivery. HTH, steep.